# Qt Visual Studio Tools for VS2019

Tags: qt, add-in, visual-studio-2019

[Qt Visual Studio Tools 2.3.0](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/11/28/qt-visual-studio-tools-2-3-0-released/) has recently been released but isn't recognised by [Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/). Does anyone know if it can be modified/rebuilt for VS2019 or when support might be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for VS2019 [has since been added](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-591) and will be available in the next version of the Qt Visual Studio Tools, which is scheduled to be released in a few days' time.

Comment: https://blog.qt.io/blog/2019/01/21/qt-visual-studio-tools-2-3-1-released/